# javafx jfx:run external .jar not recognized on eclipse

Tags: jar, runtime-error, javafx-8

**jfx:run not recognized external .jar on eclipse**

My project contains \lib folder containting my .jar that i included like a file jar on my eclipse project. A simple java application run make the application running without any problem, but when i use jfx:run, an error occured : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tllOg.png)

It seems that the class on my included .jar is not recongized. Any help please!!

Comment: First: I guess you are using the javafx-maven-plugin?! Can you provide some project for this? Sometimes it is really matters whats configured. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes i use javafx-maven-plugin. I can't provide code or java code, it's confidentiel.

Comment: I tried everything. The .jar file in \lib folder need a .DLL file. The reference to the .DLL file is made on this way : project right click > Java Build path > "my .jar" > native library location in order to point on the project folder contains my .DLL file

Comment: To find the issue, some code is required, sorry. It might be a bug in your application, or your plugin-configuration or even a bug ... but unless there is some code, it is impossible to be a better help. Just try to create a new project where this issue can be reproduced, doesnt require ALL the java-code, only for bug-reproduction. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve